# All elements of dictionary showing as type string in Python

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, request

I am trying to parse a json response from an api request in Python which is a dictionary containing various types including nested dictionaries, arrays, and strings. But when I try to iterate over the values of a nested dictionary or array, it says the object is of type string and has no values.

```
import requests
import json

def clean_data():
  r = requests.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning')
  Data = r.json()
  for data in Data['name']:
    while '' in data.values():
      del data[list(data.keys())[list(data.values()).index('')]]
  return Data
print(clean_data())
```

I expect this to print:
`{'name': {'first': 'Robert', 'last': 'Smith'}, 'age': 25, 'DOB': '-', 'hobbies': ['running', 'coding', '-'], 'education': {'highschool': 'N/A', 'college': 'Yale'}}`

But I get an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`
And when I debug, I indeed find that `Data['name']` is of type string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

def clean_data():
  r = requests.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning')
  Data = r.json()
  for data in list(Data['name']):
    if Data['name'][data] == '':
      Data['name'].pop(data)
  return Data
print(clean_data())
```

With this solution, the **output** would be:

```
{'name': {'first': 'Robert', 'last': 'Smith'}, 'age': 25, 'DOB': '-', 'hobbies': ['running', 'coding', '-'], 'education': {'highschool': 'N/A', 'college': 'Yale'}}
```